# Tracking time inside a function call - c++

Tags: c++, trace, lttng, time-tracking

One of my functions is taking more time to execute than expected. It's one of  nesteds function and these functions are spread in multiple files across a big project.

```
function1 (...) {
  function2 (...);
}

function2(...){
  function3(..)
}
...
```

I am thinking of a way to print time taken by each function call. I am not sure if it's a correct approach.
eg:

```
function1: 1.0 ms
function2: 0.8 ms
function3: 0.1 ms
```

Unfortunate I am stuck with an very old  compiler gcc-4.1.2. Is there a possibility to trace the timing of all the functions involved in user space without too much modifications in the files (because it is a big project and functions are spread across multiple files).
Or If there is a tutorial, please consider pointing me to the link.

Thanks

Comment: Profilers are handy for this kind of analysis.

Comment: Try a timer class that gets current time in constructor. In the destructor it should print current time - recorded start time. Then instantiate an instance of the timer at the begining of each function. When the function is complete, the timer instance goes out of scope, calls the destructor, and prints its message.

Comment: Something like gprof. As far as I understand it does periodic sampling of the program execution. After enough samples you can say with statistical certainty how much time was spent in each function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gprof